# How to escape ampersand (&) in soap UI

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, soapui

I am using soap UI (from smartbear) to send soap requests in xml format as :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsg="http://wsg.hpos.om.hp.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsg:abc>
      <wsg:contract>
         &lt;request&gt;

         &lt;request-attributes&gt;
            &lt;message&gt;"this &amp; and that"&lt;/message&gt;                
         &lt;/request-attributes&gt;             
         &lt;/request&gt;             
         </wsg:contract>
      </wsg:abc>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the response is : Invalid request. Could you please throw light on how to escape &?
Thanks

Comment: The `&` is escaped properly. But why are your `<` and `>` escaped?

Comment: The application is unable to read < and > tags under the body of contract and so have to use the other representation for < and >. In similar lines, when I tried &amp; for &, apparently it is not giving correct results.

Comment: Well, if you're double-encoding XML, have you tried `&amp;amp;`?

Comment: Perfect!! It did worked now :) Thanks. Could you please help me know what is double-encoding XML here?

Comment: Well, presumably whatever broken service you're sending that to is unescaping the contract body and then parsing the resulting XML.

Answer (score 21):

You could wrap the payload inside `<![CDATA[]]>` and not worry about escaping:

```
<![CDATA[<request>
    <request-attributes>
        <message>"this & and that"</message>
    </request-attributes> 
</request>]]>
```

Comment: You can also wrap individual elements in CDATA as needed.